# Backpropagation makes network worse

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

i am experimenting with neural networks. I have a network with 8 input neurons, 5 hidden and 2 output. When i let the network learn with backpropagation, sometimes, it produces worse result between single iterations of training. What can be the cause? It should not be implementation error, because i even tried using implementation from Introduction to Neural Networks for Java and it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. Back propagation is just a gradient optimization, and gradient methods do not have a guarantee of making error smaller in each iteration (you do have a guarantee that there exists a very small step size/learning rate which has such property, but in practise no way of finding it); furthermore you are probably updating weights after each sample making your training *stochastic*, which is even more "unstable" in this matter (as you do not really calculate the true gradient). However, if due to this, your method is not converging - think about proper scaling of your data as well as reducing the learning rate and probably adding the momentum term. These are just gradient-based optimization-related issues, not BP as such.